# Call method from inherited class

Tags: iphone, ios

I've got two classes A and B. In class A i use:

```
@interface A : B
```

In class B i've got this line of code:

```
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [UIBarButtonItem barItemWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Add-button-normal"]
                                                          highlightedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Add-button-active"]
                                                                    target:self
                                                                    action:@selector(showPopoverUI:)];
```

How can i access this items in class A, i try this line of code but it doesnt work:

```
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [UIBarButtonItem barItemWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Add-button-normal"]
                                                          highlightedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Add-button-active"]
                                                                    target:self.parentViewController
                                                                    action:@selector(showPopoverUI:)];
```

And i got this error:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '+[B showPopoverUI:]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x226308'
```

Comment: Your targets are different in those 2 code examples.  Try just targeting self in the second example.

Comment: Thanks Stefan! it's work. please post your answer to mark it as correct.

Comment: I added it as an answer, glad it worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are targeting the parentViewController in your second example, instead you should continue to target self.

Answer (score 1):

As you want to call a `super` class method, you need to call `super`

Instead of this you need to call `super navigationItem...`

or,

```
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [UIBarButtonItem barItemWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Add-button-normal"]
                                                          highlightedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Add-button-active"]
                                                                    target:self
                                                                    action:@selector(showPopoverUI:)];
```

Comment: you calles self.navigation, i suggest to use super.navigation or yuo need to crate an instance of super to call its navigation.

Answer (score 1):

if you are inhereting you should be able to use just self and call the method as if it was your own

Try:

```
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [UIBarButtonItem barItemWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Add-button-normal"] highlightedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Add-button-active"]target:self action:@selector(showPopoverUI:)];
```